# how to run local executable file from package.json by npm or pnpm

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, package.json, pnpm

in package.json:

```
"scripts":{
  "test": "./localPath/file.exe"
}
```

in command line:
`$ npm run test` or `$ pnpm test`

the error:
`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

extra: (tests works just fine)

1. without npm, I test in command line:
   `$ ./localPath/file.exe`
   and its run just fine
2. I test absolute path in package.json:

```
"scripts":{
  "test": "absolutePath/file.exe"
}
```

- then in command line I run
  `$ npm run test` or `$ pnpm test`
  and its run just fine